# Unicode char not display on some other computer

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode

I want to display an arrow on a label in C# on WinForms.
I use `Char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F882)` and font Arial.
It's work on my computer (Win 10) but when I install my software on a Windows Server 2016 (in a  Domain) it isn't display properly.
I try different font but it's always the same.
what is preventing my font being displayed on this server ?
thks

Comment: That looks like an emoji, which is not include in the Arial character set. I will fallback to a Font that can show it. You probably don't have a compatible Font association in the other machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem as follows : I have make a little program to display the char 0x1F882 in all avaiable fonts on the other computer (with `InstalledFontCollection`) and I found just one : 'Segoe UI Symbol'.

On the other hand in Arial it worked on my computer. Could someone guide me so that I understand the font substitution mechanism that works on my computer and not the other?
Thank you

Comment: See here: [FontFamily Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.fontfamily?view=net-5.0)